# Is it possible to tether a Panasonic Lumix G3 with Lightroom or a tablet?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lightroom, tethering, panasonic-lumix

I have a Panasonic Lumix DMC-G3.  I purchased it because it was rated the best for non-flash, low light photography, which is mostly what I do at libraries, historical societies, etc.

I saw someone using a tethered system at a state library, but didn't have a chance to ask about it.  However, I took a class at our local community college, to better learn how to use the camera, and was told that I could tether it to light room.

I recently tried it, with no luck, and from what I've read, Lightroom won't allow Panasonic tethering?

I also have trouble seeing the screen, and wondered if it were possible to tether it to my tablet.

Comment: For what its worth, Panasonic did add tethering support to the Panasonic Lumix G4, although that is a much pricer option.

Answer (score 1):

I own and have used a DMC-G3. I'm very *VERY* surprised to hear a claim that anyone's rated it "the best" at low light. It's good at low light; but not great (I also shoot a full-frame dSLR). It's a mid-grade for mirrorless and four-thirds format, which puts it on a par, handling-wise and image-quality wise, with entry-level APS-C dSLRs. I loved mine; it's a great little camera, very versatile, and a giant step up from a 1/2.3" format-sensored compact and a fantastic return on cost (I think they're going used in the $150 neighborhood), but it is **not** a high-end camera or a whiz at low light compared to other interchangeable lens cameras.

Panasonic doesn't really build tethering capability into its cameras. And as an older model, the G3 has no Wi-Fi capabilities. You're basically out of luck looking for this feature with this camera.

You may want to consider looking at a newer model with wi-fi capability (e.g., the DMC-G6 or the DMC-GX7).  While it's not exactly the same as tethered shooting, if what you're looking for is remote control over the camera, or transferring the images directly from the camera to a smart phone or tablet, then Panasonic's Image app on a smart phone or tablet, and the wi-fi capability that's built into newer Panasonic models may accomplish what you want.