# What DIY methods exist to trigger a Lumix G3 without touching the camera?

Tags: shutter, diy

I have a Panasconic Lumix DMC-G3 with a 175 mm lens which I need to trigger without touching the camera to reduce camera shake<sup>1</sup>.

I know of the following ways to take a photo without touching the camera, however at the moment I cannot use any of those:

1. Cable release: A device that you plug into your camera with a button that releases the camera shutter.

   - I don't own a cable release for this camera.
2. Intervalometer: A cable releases with the possibility to set up timers, e.g. for timelapses.

   - I don't own an intervalometer for this camera.
3. Remote Release: Similar to cable releases, but they are not plugged into the camera and work via infrared.

   - I don't own a remote release for this camera.
4. Smartphone App: Many (modern) cameras have built-in WiFi or Bluetooth which allows you to take a photo and sometimes even change settings using a smartphone app.

   - This camera has no WiFi or Bluetooth
5. PC software: Some cameras can be tethered to a PC (usually using a cable) and can be controlled and fired with some software.

   - This camera [does not have tethering capabilities](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/62378/9161)
6. Camera self-timer: Most cameras have a self-timer (e.g. 2 or 10 seconds).

   - I experienced that this can still cause camera shake when using a telephoto lens, about 3/4 of the images were shaky taken this way<sup>1</sup>.

**Are there any DIY methods than those described above to take a photo without touching the camera?**

---

<sup>1: [My other question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/117988/how-to-reduce-large-agressive-color-noise?noredirect=1#comment227627_117988) contains more information on the problem at hand: I'm trying to photograph comet C/2020 F3 (Neowise) by stacking images, but the results are too shaky.</sup>

Comment: What exactly is the point of the question? "(It can be the case...", there you make up some hypothetical situation in which none of the multiple existing solutions applies. Do you really have this problem or is it just made up for the sake of discussing it? The "[not]  purchase additional items" restriction seems to be artificial, at least to me.

Comment: @null It is the case for me that I borrowed a camera for which my cable release does not fit (other brand) and the camera has no wifi and is not recognized by PC software. I wanted to keep the question a bit more general so that it is also useful to other users.

Comment: I thought about that it might be possible to somehow send a signal to the camera using a PC even though control software does not recognize the camera

Comment: "keep the question a bit more general" your question is way too general and simply too broad. There are likely many answers to your question that will not apply to your specific situation. I highly recommend editing your question/asking a new one: what camera have you got, what are your requirements for the remote control, what are you trying to photograph and what have you tried so far. Or split it up into different questions: "Why is my camera not recognized by its dedicated PC software?", etc.

Comment: You mention your images being "shaky".  How large a telephoto lens are you using?  And how is the camera/lens being physically supported?

Comment: @null I've added information on camera & subject. Regarding PC software, I believe that the camera is simply not supported by any software as it is too old.

Comment: @PeterM I used a 175mm lens (see edited question). If you mean supported in terms of how the lens is mounted to the tripod, I've simply mounted the camera (the lens is quite small)

Comment: I don't see the point of this question. DIY options will just emulate one of the established methods already mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The self-timer should work.  If the camera is still shaking after 2 seconds, even with a big telephoto, you need a stronger tripod.  Another choice is to use a separate card as a shutter.  Set the camera for a 10 second exposure and hold a piece of cardboard in front of the lens.  Trigger the shutter, wait 8 seconds, and take the card away.

Comment: It is possible that the shutter mechanism itself is causing the shake.  But that is a great idea with the cardboard and a long exposure.

Comment: I had to extend the middle column as my tripod is comparably small (it is a travel tripod). If the wheather is clear, I will try to put the tripod on a table or something else instead of extending the middle column. Maybe this helps. Thanks for answering!

Comment: It worked perfectly! I had another try at shooting NEOWISE last night, and of my 70 images, none seems to be shaky.